# NullPointerException in multi-threading simulation with HashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, hashmap, queue

I am trying to do a multi thread simulator where there are workers (threads) and jobs to solve, so every thread has to solve a job and start to solve the next
in order, the integer of the job is the time in seconds that is required to solve the job, this is a simulation so the code prints the index of the thread with
the initialization time of the job but it hasn't to be sleeping that number of seconds.

The problem is that i'm getting a NullPointerException only when there are a lot of jobs with the same number like
4 12    (4 threads for 12 jobs)
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 (12 jobs that require 1 second to be completed) it launches the exception in this part:

```
if (workersReady.size()>1) { 
              bestWorker = workersReady.iterator().next();
              workersReady.remove(bestWorker);
              workersReadyAtTimeT.remove(currentTime);
              workersReadyAtTimeT.put(currentTime,workersReady);
              nextTimesQueue.add(currentTime);
```

The input has to be like this:

First line:
2 5 It means that there are two threads(workers) for 5 jobs

Press enter and write the second line:
1 2 3 4 5 This is the jobs that are an integer which means the time cost of processing that job so the output after press enter will be this:

0 0     The two threads try to simultaneously take jobs from the list, so thread with index 0 actually
takes the first job and starts working on it at the moment 0

1 0     Thread with index 1 takes the first job and starts working on it at the moment 0

0 1     After 1 second, thread 0 is done with the first job and takes the third job from the list, and
starts processing it immediately at time 1.

1 2     One second later, thread 1 is done with the second job and takes the fourth job from the list, and starts processing it immediately at time 2

0 4     Finally, after 2 more seconds, thread 0 is done with the third job and takes the fifth job from the list, and starts processing it immediately at time 4

This is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class JobQueue {
    private int numWorkers;
    private int[] jobs;
    private int[] assignedWorker;
    private long[] startTime;

    private FastScanner in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new JobQueue().solve();
    }

    private void readData() throws IOException {
        numWorkers = in.nextInt();
        int m = in.nextInt();
        jobs = new int[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
            jobs[i] = in.nextInt(); 
        }
    }

    private void writeResponse() {
        for (int i = 0; i < jobs.length; ++i) {
            out.println(assignedWorker[i] + " " + startTime[i]);
        }
    }

    private void assignJobs() {
        // TODO: replace this code with a faster algorithm.
        assignedWorker = new int[jobs.length];
         startTime = new long[jobs.length];
         PriorityQueue<Integer> nextTimesQueue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
         HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> workersReadyAtTimeT = new HashMap<Integer,Set<Integer>>();
         long[] nextFreeTime = new long[numWorkers];
         int duration = 0;
         int bestWorker = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
          duration = jobs[i];
          if(i<numWorkers) {
            bestWorker = i;
            nextTimesQueue.add(duration);
            addToSet(workersReadyAtTimeT, duration, i,0);
          }else {
            int currentTime = nextTimesQueue.poll();
            Set<Integer> workersReady = workersReadyAtTimeT.get(currentTime);
            if (workersReady.size()>1) { 
              bestWorker = workersReady.iterator().next();
              workersReady.remove(bestWorker);
              workersReadyAtTimeT.remove(currentTime);
              workersReadyAtTimeT.put(currentTime,workersReady);
              nextTimesQueue.add(currentTime);
            } else {
              bestWorker = workersReady.iterator().next();
              workersReadyAtTimeT.remove(currentTime);
              nextTimesQueue.add(currentTime+duration);
              addToSet(workersReadyAtTimeT, duration, bestWorker, currentTime);
            }
          }
          
          assignedWorker[i] = bestWorker;
          startTime[i] = nextFreeTime[bestWorker];
          nextFreeTime[bestWorker] += duration;
         }
        }
    
    private void addToSet(HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> workersReadyAtTimeT, int duration, int worker, int current) {
        if(workersReadyAtTimeT.get(current+duration)==null) {
          HashSet<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();
          s.add(worker);
          workersReadyAtTimeT.put(current+duration, s);
        }else {
          Set<Integer> s = workersReadyAtTimeT.get(current+duration);
          s.add(worker);
          workersReadyAtTimeT.put(current+duration,s);
         }
        }

    public void solve() throws IOException {
        in = new FastScanner();
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(System.out));
        readData();
        assignJobs();
        writeResponse();
        out.close();
    }

    static class FastScanner {
        private BufferedReader reader;
        private StringTokenizer tokenizer;

        public FastScanner() {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            tokenizer = null;
        }

        public String next() throws IOException {
            while (tokenizer == null || !tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
            }
            return tokenizer.nextToken();
        }

        public int nextInt() throws IOException {
            return Integer.parseInt(next());
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I used a ConcurentHashMap and still launching NullPointer

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is not threadsafe.

If you interact with a hashmap from multiple threads without 'external' synchronization, then the spec of HashMap says anything is fair game. If your computer starts playing Yankee Doodle Dandee, that would be compatible with the spec, and no bug report would be accepted on that account.

In other words, you *MUST* take care of this yourself.

Usually, the right move is to use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead (from the extremely useful `java.util.concurrent` package), and so it is here.

If you must, you can externally synchronize as well. For example:

```
synchronized (workersReady) {
    // interact with workersReady here
}
```

but `synchronized` is a pretty clumsy cudgel to use here, and may well remove most/all of the benefits of trying to multithread this stuff.

Note that a 'pool of workers' sounds more like a job for e.g. `ExecutorPool`. Make sure to check the j.u.c package, I'm pretty sure it has something much more appropriate so you can delete most of what you wrote and use a carefully tweaked solution, pre-tested and optimized.

Comment: I am starting to learn about data structures and I don't know how to implement that could you help me please? Is there any faster way to do what I'm trying the execution speed is my priority

Comment: Use [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) - and have threads pull jobs off of it.

Comment: Still launching NullPointer

Comment: Post a new question with yoru CLQ based code then; updating this one seems inappropriate and I can't help you without code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63142899/updated-code-of-nullpointerexception-problem-with-concurrenthashmap

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: Still launching NullPointer